# Zero volume / zero Jordan measure equivalent to content zero

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, measure-theory

A set $R=[a_1,b_1]\times\cdots\times[a_n,b_n]$ is called (closed) $n$-$\textbf{rectangle}$. Its volume is $\ |R|=(b_1-a_1)\cdots(b_n-a_n)$.

Let $D\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded set.

$\textbf{Definition 1.}$  $D$ is a $\textbf{rectifiable}$ set if there exists a $n$-rectangle $R\supset D$ such that the indicator function $1_D:\ R\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ is (Riemannian) integrable, and its $\textbf{volume}$ is defined as $$\ |D|=\displaystyle\intop_R1_D.$$

The Definition 1 is equivalent to the follow statement : $D$ is a rectifiable if $\partial D$ is of content zero.

$\textbf{Definition 2.}$  $D$ is a set of (Jordan) $\textbf{content zero}$ if $\ \forall\varepsilon>0,\ \exists\ n$-rectangles $R_1,\dots,R_m$ such that

$$D\subseteq\displaystyle\bigcup_{i=1}^mR_i\ \text{ and } \ \displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^m|R_i|<\varepsilon.$$

My problem is to show that $D$ is of content zero iff $D$ is rectifiable and $|D|=0$.

This is my proof for the forward part.

Suppose $D$ is of content zero. Then from [Content $0$ implies boundary has content $0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/783177/content-0-implies-boundary-has-content-0), $\partial D$ also has content zero, which implies $D$ is rectifiable.

From the definition of content zero, given $\varepsilon>0$, we have $n$-rectangles $R_1,\dots,R_m$ such that

\begin{align}0\leq|D|=\displaystyle\intop_R1_D & \leq\intop_R{1_{\bigcup R_i}}\\ 
&=\intop_R\sum_{i=1}^m1_{R_i}
\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^m\intop_R 1_{R_i}
\\ &=\sum_{i=1}^m|R_i|<\varepsilon.\end{align}
So, $\forall\varepsilon>0,\ 0\leq |D|<\varepsilon$. Hence, $|D|=0$.

However, the converse of the problem seems quite tricky, and I have no idea to deal with it. Is there anyone with any interesting ideas for this problem ? I'm very appreciated.

Comment: $|D| = 0$ means there is partition with upper Darboux sum $< \epsilon$. Such partition corresponds to cover.

Comment: Do you meant that :
Since $1_D$ is integrable, for any $\varepsilon>0$, there exists partition $P$ of $R$ such that $U(1_D,P)-L(1_D,P)<\varepsilon$. But $U(1_D,P) = \displaystyle\sum_{I\cap D\ne\varnothing}|I|$ and $L(1_D,P)=\displaystyle\sum_{I\subseteq D}|I|=0$ since $|D|=0$, therefore $\displaystyle\sum_{I\cap D\ne\varnothing}
|I|<\varepsilon $ ?

Comment: But I have one more querry here, we already have $|D|=0$, if $I\subseteq D$, how do we show that $|I|=0$ ?

Comment: Yes, correct. To show that rectifiable subset of zero-volume set has zero volume, use monotonicity of integral (if $f \leq g$ then $\int f \leq \int g$).

Comment: thank you for your support, it is so amazing and helpful to me